# yii2:change FCKConfig.DefaultLinkTarget to "_blank" in ckeditor

Tags: yii2, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, yii2-extension

i want change default target to _blank in create link

---

> 'DefaultLinkTarget' => '_blank',

---

how to can do this !

```
   <?php

use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;

?>

 <?=
    $form->field($model, 'summary')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 1],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'language' => 'fa',
//            'DefaultLinkTarget' => '_blank',
            'height' => '200'
        ],
        'preset' => 'full',
    ])
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the options  target

```
  <?=
      $form->field($model, 'summary')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
          'options' => ['rows' => 1, 'target' =>'_blank'],
          'clientOptions' => [
              'language' => 'fa',
  //            'DefaultLinkTarget' => '_blank',
              'height' => '200'
          ],
          'preset' => 'full',
      ])
      ?>
```

or try add  a script in your page

```
<script> 
 // Sets the default config value to _blank.
 CKEDITOR.config.DefaultLinkTarget = '_blank';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about CKEditor or FCKeditor but in CKEditor there is no such config setting. You need to use [dialogDefinition](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition) event for that. The code would be:

```
<script> 
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { });

CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( ev.data.name == 'link' ){
        dialogDefinition.getContents( 'target' ).get( 'linkTargetType' )['default'] = '_blank';
    }
});
</script>
```